# Software to compute generators of a module over polynomial ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra, mathematical-software

Let $A=\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the algebra of real polynomials in $n$ variables. Fix polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_k\in A$.

Consider the subset
$$M:=\{(q_1,\dots,q_k)\in A^k|\, p_1q_1+\dots+p_kq_k=0\}.$$
Clearly $M$ is an $A$-submodule of $A^k$. Necessarily $M$ is finitely generated.

**I am wondering if there exists a software which allows to compute explicit generators of $M$ as an $A$-module.**

In my case $n=16,k=10$, and all $p_i$'s are explicit homogeneous polynomials of second degree.

Comment: Would macaulay2 could help? You may check http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.18/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_computing_spsyzygies.html.

Comment: In SageMath there is also the command [syzygy_module](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_ideal.html#sage.rings.polynomial.multi_polynomial_ideal.MPolynomialIdeal_singular_repr.syzygy_module) built on the function [syz](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-3/sing_902.htm) in singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you compute is the "*syzygy module*" of $p_1,\ldots,p_k$.

You can try the following M2 script to check the computation times in Macaulay 2 for different $n$'s and $k$'s.

For me $n=16, k=6$ was a matter of minutes, but $k > 6$ seems to take much longer.

If you decrease the sparsity of your $p_i$ by setting Density to 0.1, 0.5 or higher, you will probably be out of luck with your computation.

```
n = 16
k = 10
R=QQ
--- or R=ZZ/23 or any other prime
A=R[x_1..x_n]
mat = random(A^1, A^{k:-2}, Density=>0.05)
erz = gens ker mat
```